# How to fix htaccess 500 ERROR on linux localhost

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, localhost

When i use sudo a2enmode rewrite Module rewrite already enabled.

this is /etc/apache2/apache2.conf (i deleted # lines)

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.



DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}


PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}


Timeout 300


KeepAlive On


MaxKeepAliveRequests 100


KeepAliveTimeout 5


User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}


HostnameLookups Off


ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log


LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>






AccessFileName .htaccess


<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent


IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

this is `.htaccess` codes;

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^urun-detay-([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)-([0-9]+)$  urun-detay.php?sef=$1&urun_id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^kategori-([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)-([0-9]+)$  kategori.php?sef=$1&kategori_id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^yazi-([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)-([0-9]+)$  yazi.php?sef=$1&blog_id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

I changed allowoverride None to All, and i enabled rewrite module...

Comment: You need to check the error log for the details of the 500 error. At what point do you get this error? What makes you think it is a problem with `.htaccess`? What request are you making? This config is incomplete. You have two `IncludeOptional` directives at the end that likely includes the necessary (vHost?) configs. You should **not** set `AllowOverride All` in the `<Directory />` container as you have done.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I edited the .htaccess file with notepad++ and there was a character in the first line, and when I deleted it and saved, it was fixed. (didn't show up in phpstorm or other editors)